# mkNP contain additional determiner in GF

Tags: gf

I'm trying to output the following sentence in Italian `un anno e mezzo` where the sentence is a noun-phrase-list. My code:

```hs
lin
   Sentence = mkUtt(mkNP
         (and_Conj)
         (mkNP (aSg_Det) (mkN("anno")))
         (mkNP (mkN("mezzo")))
   );
```

But the output of the above code is `un anno ed il mezzo`. Why I have the `il` determiner in my output? I couldn't find the reason behind this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Mass nouns in the RGL

You're getting the output with *il*, because the `N -> NP` instance of `mkNP` makes **mass nouns**. The canonical example is *"I drink water"*, where *water* is constructed with `mkNP water_N`.

In some resource grammars, this `mkNP` instance creates NPs without any article: like English *"I drink water"*. In other languages like French, it creates a NP in partitive: "je bois de l'eau". Italian gives, not the bare form like English, nor a partitive like French, but a normal definite article: *"bevo l'acqua"*.

Why would the RGL creators do this? When writing an application grammar, the `mkNP : N -> NP` instance is a higher-level construct for *mass noun*, rather than a lower-level question of "do I put an article or not".

The downsides are that it's almost impossible to ever output a bare form in the languages where `mkN : N -> NP` adds an article. As far as I understand, it's possible only as a standalone utterance, see e.g. [this answer](https://groups.google.com/g/gf-dev/c/RSB0PwSiCHU/m/YXjZDJfsAQAJ) on the GF mailing list.

```
Lang> p "king John" | l -treebank
Lang: UttCN (ApposCN (UseN king_N) (UsePN john_PN))
LangEng: king John
LangSpa: rey Juan
Lang: UttNP (MassNP (ApposCN (UseN king_N) (UsePN john_PN)))
LangEng: king John
LangSpa: el rey Juan
```

If you want true articleless NPs on the NP level, you can add such a function (`CN -> NP`) to the Extend module, or create an issue on [RGL's github](https://github.com/GrammaticalFramework/gf-rgl/issues) asking that someone else creates such a function.

### How to solve your current problem

So what to do if you want to output *un anno e mezzo*? I would just be lazy and make "e mezzo" into an adverbial, and then attach it to *anno*. Like this:

```hs
 Sentence =
      mkUtt (mkNP
               aSg_Det
               (mkCN
                  (mkN "anno")
                  (ParadigmsIta.mkAdv "e mezzo")
               )
            ) ;
```

You can do this safely, because *e mezzo* doesn't inflect. *Anno* is the head of the noun phrase, and only it needs to inflect.